# Optimization of INSERT Query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I am investigating on comparing the effectiveness of two ways of `INSERT` data in `SQL` to know which executes faster

The first one is

```
INSERT INTO mytb(id, name)
   select 0, 'uyen' union all
   select 1, 'uyen' union all
   ....
   select 1000, 'uyen'
```

and the second one is:

```
INSERT INTO mytb(id, name) values (0,'uyen');
INSERT INTO mytb(id, name) values (1,'uyen');
....
INSERT INTO mytb(id, name) values (1000,'uyen');
```

I have tried executing those with 1000 rows. Sometimes this runs faster and sometimes the other runs faster (I think this is because the resources of the system is different in every execution or any other issues). I did search around the internet without success. Could you please help me give the answer and explain the reasons. I want to know this to do some optimization for my queries.

Thanks

Comment: Don't think there will be any considerable difference on just 1000 inserts. First one might be just a little faster because of reduced overhead of executing multiple queries and since your first query is not selecting records from any table that might be faster

Comment: You can also do  `INSERT INTO mytb(id,name) VALUES (0,'uyen'),(1,'uyen')` etc

Comment: *Use a transaction* around all the individual insert statements. Then they will be 'the same speed' for a low-latency connection. For a *high-latency* connection (in the dozens of milliseconds or more) less command (and less server round trips) may be faster, fsvo. However in other cases the work 'will be the same' if an explicit transaction is used around the individual inserts. This is definitely a duplicate.